# Zotero does not lauch

Tags: desktop-apps, zotero

I used the Ubuntu app shop to install Zotero. Installation went without problems but Zotero does not start. The icon "flashes" quickly but nothing else happens. What should I do?

Comment: open a terminal, start it from there and post the output

Comment: That would not be the first snap package that is broken. You may need to install using the software provided on the zotero website instead.

Comment: @j-money Thank you for the info and tips. I thought that the app shop was the best / safest place... I reinstalled from Zotero and it works again.

Comment: @vanadium please see above

Comment: Interestingly, it stopped working after the computer updated programmes...

Answer (score 1):

As of 2019, the preferred way of installing Zotero is by using [Emiliano Heyns' packages](https://github.com/retorquere/zotero-deb).

Run the following instructions on your terminal:

```sh
wget -qO- https://github.com/retorquere/zotero-deb/releases/download/apt-get/install.sh | sudo bash
sudo apt update
sudo apt install zotero
```

For additional information about the provided packages, see the [README file](https://github.com/retorquere/zotero-deb/blob/master/README.md).

Other answers should be considered obsolete, Sebastiaan Mathot's packages being [no longer maintained](https://launchpad.net/~smathot/+archive/ubuntu/cogscinl).

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by [vanadium](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1124724/zotero-does-not-lauch#comment1861009_1124724) and [described on the Zotero website](https://www.zotero.org/support/installation), this worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04:

Download Zotero from the [Zotero website](https://www.zotero.org/download/).

In your terminal, in your Downloads folder, extract and move the folder to `/opt/`.
Adjust for correct version, I downloaded 5.0.89.

```
tar xjf Zotero-5.0.89_linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
sudo mv Zotero-5.0.89_linux-x86_64 /opt/Zotero
```

To get an launcher icon to work, run `set_icon_launcher` and create symlink:

```
cd /opt/Zotero
bash set_icon_launcher
ln -s /opt/Zotero/zotero.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/zotero.desktop
```

Good luck!